# EF6 - stopped dropping and recreating database

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I was learning Entity Framework 6, and was successful with dropping and recreating the DB using:

```
    public class SchoolInitializer : System.Data.Entity.DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<SchoolContext>
```

But then, I don't know what happened, I tried deleting an entry from the UI in my MVC site, and then when I tried to open the site again, the entry is still gone, I can't seem to drop the DB and recreate it automatically in my initializer.

I tried debugging my initializer class to try to reach the point where it saves my entities to the DB, but it doesn't stop at that point. Is there something wrong am doing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The **DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges** initializer specifies that only when you change your model clasess the db will be dropped and recreated. 
This means that if you change a property type, add or delete properties or clasess to your model, but NOT if you just delete a row.

If you want the database to be dropped and recreated every time you run the application yo can use the **DropCreateDatabaseAlways** initializator.

Comment: But what do you mean by "change your model classes", isn't adding or deleting a property means changing the model class?